# two-column unequal width with a list of "property : value" items

Tags: tables, typography

here is a document i did with a wysiwyg tool, i'd like a latex code doing something similar. Font must be sans, size could be smaller, default when setting \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} should be fine.
[image]

Comment: Other possibilities are paracol or a tabular.

Answer (score 1):

## New Answer

The following is a reimplementation, using the same input syntax, but being completely page breakable (utilizing the `paracol` package). Output looks like below (except that I've changed the indentation of the more details, from half the line width to 40% of the linewidth, giving them a bit more space).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\dollar[1]{\$\num[detect-all]{#1}}

\newcommand\details[1]
  {%
    \par
    \begingroup
      % change .4 to your liking for the indent of the more details
      \advance\leftskip.4\linewidth
      \itshape#1\par
    \endgroup
  }
\newenvironment{itemdetails}[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \sffamily
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      \noindent
      \ul{item description}
      \begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}%
      \switchcolumn
      \noindent
      \ul{rates and delivery details}
      \begin{itemize}%
  }
  {%
      \end{itemize}%
    \end{paracol}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\vspace*{.7\textheight}
\begin{itemdetails}
  {set of 4 luxurious hand crafted white wood chairs and table for living room}
  \item
    items arrived on
    \details{1\textsuperscript{st}, January 2021}
  \item
    cost per item
    \details{\dollar{1100}}
  \item
    discount
    \details
      {%
        \dollar{3000} if 3 items taken at once, and delivery free of
        charge\par
        \dollar{5900} same as above for 6 items
      }
  \item
    payment should be made directly online
  \item
    date of delivery of first batch
    \details{8\textsuperscript{th}, May 2021}
\end{itemdetails}
\end{document}
```

---

## Old answer

*Caveat: This is not page-breakable.*

The following is an example implementation, that should come close to your image. Note that underlining isn't typographical best practice, and the support in LaTeX for underlining text is quite limited (things turn better if you're using LuaLaTeX and the `lua-ul` package).

The following uses `soul` for the underlining and works in every major engine.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\dollar[1]{\$\num[detect-all]{#1}}

\newcommand\details[1]
  {%
    \\\null\hfill
    \parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{\parskip=\itemsep\raggedright\itshape#1}%
  }
\newenvironment{itemdetails}[1]
  {%
    \par
    \noindent
    \begingroup
    \sffamily
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
      \ul{item description}
      \begin{flushleft}#1\end{flushleft}%
    \end{minipage}\hfil
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.55\linewidth}
      \ul{rates and delivery details}
      \begin{itemize}%
  }
  {%
      \end{itemize}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \endgroup
    \par
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{itemdetails}
  {set of 4 luxurious hand crafted white wood chairs and table for living room}
  \item
    items arrived on
    \details{1\textsuperscript{st}, January 2021}
  \item
    cost per item
    \details{\dollar{1100}}
  \item
    discount
    \details
      {%
        \dollar{3000} if 3 items taken at once, and delivery free of
        charge\par
        \dollar{5900} same as above for 6 items
      }
  \item
    payment should be made directly online
  \item
    date of delivery of first batch
    \details{8\textsuperscript{th}, May 2021}
\end{itemdetails}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks good, however it seems to not break over two pages if the remaining space is not enough on the current page. Also for the titles it would be better if their could be passed as arguments to the environment or a new macro like \title is used instead of being entered in the macro definition.

Comment: @user1850133 yes, these are not page-breakable. If you need this, take a look at some dedicated packages, like for example [`paracol`](https://texdoc.net/pkg/paracol).

Comment: can you explain \begingroup ... \endgroup?

Comment: `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` form a group, keeping changes like those by `\itshape`, or `\advance\leftskip` local to that group. They are roughly the same as `{` and `}`, but more verbose, easier to spot, and can only be matched by each other, which is why they are preferred for programming macros (while you'd use `{` and `}` in your text).

Comment: changes like \itshape, \advance\leftskip, but not \noindent?

Comment: @user1850133 `\noindent` is no switch. It just suppresses the indentation of the *current* paragraph at which's start it's used.